# not updating my access database

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, ms-access

```
public void UpdateSales()
{
    OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection();
        connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\rango\Documents\posisdb_ibra.accdb;
        Persist Security Info=False;";
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(@"UPDATE Transactions SET VatAmount = VatAmount - @vat, NonVatTotal =NonVatTotal- @nonvat,  TotalAmount =TotalAmount- @totalam  WHERE InvoiceNo =@txt", connect);
        command.Connection = connect;
        command.Parameters.Add("@vat", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(lblVAT.Text.Replace(",", ""));
        command.Parameters.Add("@nonvat", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(lblSubTotal.Text.Replace(",", ""));
        command.Parameters.Add("@totalam", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(lblTotalAmount.Text.Replace(",", ""));
        command.Parameters.Add("@txt", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = lblInvoice.Text;
 try
    {
        connect.Open(); // opting connection
    }
    catch (Exception expe)
    {
        //Interaction.MsgBox(expe.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(expe.Source);
    }
    try
    {
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("DATA UPDATED");
    }
    catch (Exception expe)
    {
        //Interaction.MsgBox(expe.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(expe.Source);
    }
    finally
    {
        connect.Close(); // closing connection
    }
}
```

code runs well with no error but it doesnot update my database have tried all option what could be wrong am using ms access it is supposed to subtract values in database

Comment: You haven’t executed the command

Comment: You haven't opened the connection

Comment: And after all the above, do no use AddWithValue in particular when you deal with decimal values and date values (automatic conversion could not be right for what the database expects)

Comment: mat and steve i have updated my code

Comment: steve wat should i use if not addwithvalue

Comment: You use Add specifying the datatype of the parameter and passing an appropriate value converted to the specific datatype. For example _command.Add("@vat", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(lblVat.Text));_

Comment: Also, read back the value returned by ExecuteNonQuery. It is the number of rows updated in the table. If it is zero then the Where clause doesn't find record matching, if it is 1 then you are updating a different database than the one you are looking for changes.

Comment: And when you want to address someone in a comment add @ before the user name. The user will be notified in that way.

Comment: @Steve pleasse look thru code hav updates it as u said still not updating

Comment: Yes, what is the return value of ExecuteNonQuery? _int rows = command.ExecuteNonQuery(); MessageBox.Show(rows);_

Comment: @Steve return is zero

Comment: This means that the Where clause doesn't find a record to update. What is the value of _lblInvoice.Text_? Pay attention to white spaces. You search for = so any white space could give a wrong result.

Comment: I also would try with _OleDbType.VarWChar_ for strings

Comment: @Steve  same issue, thankx anyway for quick response

Comment: whats the data type in the database...does the data include whitespace at the beginning or end?